# Is it possible to open a browser through react-native-inappbrowser-reborn and then close that browser once the web application sends an event?

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-inappbrowser-reborn

I have the following scenario - I have a React Native application which opens a browser through react-native-inappbrowser-reborn but I also want to close this browser programatically once a specific action has been completed in the browser.

Is there a way for me to listen for some sort of event send from the web application, and close the browser once the event is emitted?

Comment: I managed to communicate with the inappbrowser through a deeplink

Answer (score 0):

As of my knowledge, there is no way to communicate with in app browser.

How about using react-native-webview?

It can be communicated with postMessage.